# Why does my IP being leaked with system-wide proxy through webTRC, but it doesn't happen when I use system-wide VPN

Tags: vpn, proxy, anonymity, fingerprinting, webrtc

WebRTC manages to leak my IP when I use proxy, but when I use VPN it only shows VPN server's IP (both proxy and VPN were system-wide). What's the key difference? Google Chrome was used in both tests (webRTC leak test). https://browserleask.com — site I used to run both tests. It also doesn't matter whether I use local TOR 127.0.0.1:9150 proxy or remote proxy server. Results were the same.

Comment: Are you using http proxy server? STUN request will not pass through http proxy so it goes directly. VPN creates virtual route to carry request from the tunnel.

Comment: Yes. Is there any ways to prevent client from sending anything directly. Make it "forced", block any requests that don't go through tor?

And even so. Lets hypothetically say I managed to achieve it (direct requests can't leave my client). Would there be any other ways to get my real IP or identify me other way?

Comment: In the Tor Browser, WebRTC is disabled by default for this exact reason. As it solves the problem, what's the reason behind searching for another solution?

Comment: It is said that there are other ways Tor Browser can break your anonymity through javascript leakage. I just want to be sure that it won't happen. There's no telling how many other unpatched "holes" that would allow client to send packets directly there are. I'd like to be able prevent any application from sending them on a system level without using TAILS or disabling javascript

Comment: @infinitieunique: I think your expectation are above of what can be delivered. You are refusing to use a tool (Tails) which was specifically designed by experts to provide as much anonymity as possible while still being comfortable to use - because it might impact anonymity in some cases. Instead you want to create a more comfortable system yourself which should even provide more anonymity. High ambitions but unlikely too achieve.

Comment: There's no known unpatched vulnerability in Tor right now that can be exploited by JavaScript to discover your real IP Address.

Comment: How did they manage to configure TOR in a way that doesn't allow to get an IP? I heard that it is extremely hard to acheive and that you only can be 100% anonymous if you disable javascript. https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/203361/can-javascript-break-anonimity-provided-by-tor. Also canvas fingerprinting test on https://browserleaks.com shows that I'm 100% unique

Comment: JS can't expose your real IP Address. You heard it wrong.